# AWS Glue -Add prefix to Job output file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

AWS Glue job default output file name start with jr_. When I refer these logs under Cloud Watch logstream, its very difficult to find specific job.

Anyone know If I can rename these or add prefix/suffix ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific job ID, you can use CloudWatch logs insights to query for that specific job, e.g.

```
fields @timestamp, @logStream, @message
| filter @logStream like /*job id*/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

For more information, refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/cloudwatch-logs-reading.html

Comment: Well ! this is after the fact where hundreds of logs are already generated and want to search something. However if I can give meaningful name in the first place than it makes everything easy. Something like - "ABC-XYZ-Jr_0e89asjdasjdjlajd"

Comment: Is there any information that you would know in advance that could help you effectively search through the logs? At a minimum, you have the following fields to parse: ingestionTime, log, logStream, message, timestamp

Comment: thanks! but this question is not about how to parse/filter logs. My question is on how can I give meaningful name to these aws glue output log files instead of "jr_<someRandomstring>"